# After opening a webpage, check if it has opened before proceeding

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to create a chrome extension that, with a click of a button opens several webpages that I often visit. Currently when clicked it opens 1-4 of the 4 webpages I want it to, often stopping prematurely. The code is pretty simple, so I figured it is a processing issue. For this reason I want to introduce some delay. I've been told not to use sleep() from the research I have found so I am trying to implement code that makes my For loop wait until the page has loaded before proceeding. Here is the code:

```js
function OpenInNewTabWinBrowser(url) {
  var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
  //win.focus();
}

function CheckLoading() {
  return document.readyState === "interactive";
}

var websites = ['https://reddit.com', 'https://xkcd.com', 'http://poorlydrawnlines.com', 'https://explosm.net'];
var MoveAlong;

for (var i = websites.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
  OpenInNewTabWinBrowser(websites[i]);
  console.log("Just opened a window!");
  MoveAlong = CheckLoading();
  console.log("Just checked if it was loading!");
  /*while (MoveAlong == false) {
   console.log("Just realized it hasn't loaded all the way!");
   sleep(10);
   console.log("Just woke up!");
   
   MoveAlong = CheckLoading();
   console.log("Just double checked if it had loaded!")
  }
  console.log("Just broke out of the while loop!")*/
}
console.log("Just finished doing everything you asked master!")
```

When I run the code as is I don't always open every page. The commented section is what I have tried to utilize as a pausing function but when that code is un-commented it only opens up one page and never anymore. I have also tried supplying console.log comments for debugging but when I inspect popup if even one window opens up the console closes itself and I am left with no means of reading where the code went wrong.

I have also tried this loop and function to check for a loaded page and then unpause. This code replaced the For loop from the snippet above. It also didn't work correctly.

```js
var i = websites.length - 1;

do {
  MoveAlong = false;
  OpenInNewTabWinBrowser(websites[i]);
  i--;
  window.onload = function() {
    MoveAlong = true;
  }
}
while (MoveAlong == true && i >= 0);
```

Any help is much appreciated. On how to properly debug, on how to detect if the website is loading, on how to make this extension work. I have been a partial lurker for a while but now I am trying to actively code every day. This is my first post and hopefully it will be the beginning to a fun hobby. Thank you again.

Comment: if you open a new window (blank) you dont have access to the communication to the tabs. Event the postmessage doesnt allow such thing so i dont think this is possible

Comment: If you're writing this as a Chrome extension, then you can use [chrome.tabs.create](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create) to open the new tabs.

Comment: Your code checks current window/document state that has nothing to do with the opened windows.